# ORA-01691 (unable to extend lob segment) even though my tablespace has AUTOEXTEND on

Tags: oracle, tablespaces

I am getting an error:

```
ORA-01691: unable to extend lob segment ABC.SYS_LOB0000167347C00131$$ by 1024 in tablespace XYZ
```

But this is very strange to me because the tablespace has AUTOEXTEND on. What is the likely reason that this happens and how can I overcome it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Autoextensible datafiles still have a size limit.

```
select file_id, bytes, maxbytes from dba_data_files where tablespace_name = 'XYZ';
```

Maxbytes is the maximum size of the datafile, it can not grow beyond that. If bytes = maxbytes, you have two options:

1) increase the maximum size (maxbytes) as (15 is the file_id from above query), for example to 10G:

```
alter database datafile 15 autoextend on maxsize 20G;
```

Datafiles have a hard limit for the maximum size, it is `2^22 * block_size` for smallfile tablespaces, and `2^32 * block_size` for bigfile tablespaces.

If you use a tablespace with 8K block size, then the maximum size of your datafile is 32 GB. If your datafile is already at that size, you can not increase it any further, there comes option number two:

2) add a new datafile to the tablespace, for example:

```
alter tablespace xyz add datafile '/path/to/datafiles/xyz02.dbf' size 100M autoextend on next 100M maxsize unlimited;
```